# Facebook 360 Photo sphere sharing

Tags: php, facebook, sharing

У нас есть неразрешенная проблемка/задание.

Мы хотим "шарить" наши панорамы на аккаунты пользователей соцсети Facebook, которые были сделаны с помощью [LG 360 Cam](http://www.lg.com/us/mobile-accessories/lg-LGR105.AVRZTS-360-cam).
Фотосферы физически храняться у нас на сервере.

Как, и можно ли, "шарить" фотосферы с внешнего источника через ссылку с нашего сайта?
Работают ли `og` теги для шаринга панорам?

Данный вопрос являеться копией моего [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42248017/facebook-360-photo-sphere-sharing) на англоязычном сообществе.